# Charting Solution for Windows Service

Tags: c#, charts, data-visualization

I need to create 100s of graph through automation, I try couple of library for charting from codeplex. however none of them works for me as they all expect either a WPF or Windows Forms interface to be present. Since I need the task to be done using Background windows service such libraries won't work for me.

I am not stuck to use ZedGraph, yeah it is one of the best library, but the Chart quality is way too dim, I use MSChart with ASP.NET projects of mine, they have such a smooth curves, but ZedGraph doesn't.

Now my only question is: Which is the best library in terms of visual as well as in terms of feature like zedgraph to use for windows service. I prefer if someone tell me how I can improve zedgraph really quick if possible.

Comment: How do you want to "view" these charts? Will they be output as PDFs, JPEGS, PNG, Excel files?

Comment: yes they will be attach to PDF, along with other Data Table and textual information.

Comment: Not sure what you have access to but Microsoft Reporting Services has the ability to output charts, tables, textual information etc into Excel, PDF etc.

Comment: I never heard of it, please shade some light on it...

Comment: I have been using both win charts & Zedgraph for last 2 years, Zedgraph is far better than Win Charts, not only the features, appearance but the performance too. You mentioned Chart quality is too dim??? could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @San, I was trying to create a Curve Graph, but curves are not smooth and they are not smooth. If you know any method to make them look little silky/glossy look?

Comment: @San see the difference in these samples : http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/linesamples.html is what Zedgraph provide, but I am looking for something like : http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/ or what you usually see in Excel Charts.

Comment: @Sumit, I understand what you are trying to achieve, zedgraph can be customized, here's a small sample: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11779274/1463551

Comment: @Sumit, If you are looking beyond then Zedgraph is not a right choice, you may have look for some paid tools: such as telerik: http://www.telerik.com/ , nevron : http://www.nevron.com/Products.ChartFor.NET.Overview.aspx & etc

Comment: I have used ZedGRaph in quite a few projects, but those were mainly bar graph etc and I can control their look, but with line graph it become not so good. Thanks for option I will look on them, but my budget is doesn't allow more than $200 paid software :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SQL Server you could use Microsoft's [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/reporting.aspx) which is abbreviated to SSRS. This is similar to Crystal Reports in so much as you can design your report with graphs, tables, textual information etc and then when run the information is populated from your database.

SSRS can be called either by a front-end application or simply as a web service call (via your Windows Service) that can generate the report and save to either Excel, PDF etc.

This is industry recognised and a good place to go if you already have SQL Server. I also mentioned Crystal Reports that you may also want to check out.

Comment: Well we don't have access to paid version of SQL server, having said I can get my client to install SQL Server Express, but SSRS is not available with it. Right?

Comment: I believe SQL Server Express has a limited version: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: thanks, looks like lot of reading to do :), I will check it out. Thanks again.