# Getting a certain value/point

Tags: zedgraph

Is there a way to get the value at x, y in the graph, where the symbol is? We can add as a parameter, "SymbolType.Star" etc, then ZedGraph will add the symbols at certain points x, y. I have have som values, and I want to make a bar chart, but right now, a curve is drawn. The bar chart should be made from the same values that the curve is created, but it should not draw the (somewhat) straight line through i, j, but rather a vertical line. I'm not sure how to go about with this. Below is the code I have, and I want to retain the value at xVal, yVal

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables[objectName].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                xVal[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataSet.Tables[objectName].Rows[i][resForXAxis]);
                yVal[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataSet.Tables[objectName].Rows[i][resForYAxis]);

            }
```

Comment: you question isn't clear, Title says `Getting a certain value/point` and you are asking about `Bar chart` in detail, can u specify what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Yea, I just realize that. Sorry about that. I want to get the value at xVal, yVal.

Comment: @AomSet Then please edit your question so that it shows what you really want to know. No more, no less.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the x & y value of the mouse location, try this: 
[ReverseTransform Method](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_GraphPane_ReverseTransform_3.htm)

&

There's a similar solution, check this out: [How to find the index position on ZedGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779274/how-to-find-the-index-position-on-zedgraph)